# How can i set default SMS permission to my App android?

Tags: android, sms, call, smsmanager

I have added permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` and `IntentFilter`. In `DialerActivity` I have created `Fragments` to manage all SMS, Contact and Call Log that working fine.

```
        <activity android:name=".turecaller.DialerActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />

                <data android:scheme="tel" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="sms" />
                <data android:scheme="smsto" />
                <data android:scheme="mms" />
                <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

and this is my SMS BROADCAST RECEIVER

```
<receiver
            android:name=".ServicesPack.SMSBroadCastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="998">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `manifest` on top of(outside) `<application tag>`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is about OTP, for SMS retrieving you should be using Google's SMS retriever API,

https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview

Comment: I don't want to read SMS just want to know Incoming SMS caller number.

Comment: Use the [getOriginatingAddress](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsMessage.html#getOriginatingAddress%28%29) method.

Comment: Inside onReceive() of your listener,

`if(intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {  
 for (SmsMessage smsMessage : Telephony.Sms.Intents.getMessagesFromIntent(intent)) {
  smsSender = smsMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
  smsBody += smsMessage.getMessageBody();
 }   
}`